# Why We Are Using This Loop For Clean Layout

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm creating a program to show some record details:

```
employeeid = self.employeelist.currentItem().text()[0]
query = f"Select * From myemployees where id = {employeeid}"
result = cur.execute(query).fetchone()
img = QLabel()
img.setPixmap(QPixmap(f"Images/{result[5]}"))
name = QLabel(result[1])
surname = QLabel(result[2])
phone = QLabel(result[3])
email = QLabel(result[4])
address = QLabel(result[6])
self.leftLayout.setVerticalSpacing(20)
self.leftLayout.addRow("", img)
self.leftLayout.addRow("Name: ", name)
self.leftLayout.addRow("Surname: ", surname)
self.leftLayout.addRow("Phone: ", phone)
self.leftLayout.addRow("E-Mail: ", email)
```

But there is a problem with this code: when I click other records, my details are not written over to the old one, but to bottom of the old ones.

So I looked up how to delete old details and write new details from records. I found the solution but I didn't understand why I should use this for loop:

```
for i in reversed(range(self.leftLayout.count())):
    widget = self.leftLayout.takeAt(i).widget()

    if widget is not None:
        widget.deleteLater()
```

Can anyone explain it to me? Thank you for all answers in advance and again sorry for my English.

Comment: try `self.employeelist.clear()` at the beginning of your other records method code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt objects are very complex and, in order to delete them, it's sometimes better to call [`deleteLater()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater), which is a function that ensures that those objects are "gracefully" deleted/destroyed and possibly free up system resources.

In your case, the widgets have been added to a layout manager (a system that ensures that all widget are correctly aligned and resized) and the for cycle is used to "clear" that layout.

A layout manager uses layout "items" ([QLayoutItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayoutitem.html)), which are abstract objects that "contain" widgets or other nested layouts. If the layout item is used for a widget, calling `item.widget()` will return that widget.

[`count()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#count) returns the number of items in the layout.

[`takeAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#takeAt) is used to remove an item from the layout, and the reverse order is required because if you remove items in an ascending index order you'll end up removing only half of them.

Let's say you have 4 widgets:

```
[widget_1, widget_2, widget_3, widget_4]
```

- start a loop using a `for i in range(self.leftLayout.count())`
- `i` is 0, so `takeAt(0)` will return the first item (`widget_1`)
- if the item has a widget, delete it (*later*)
- now the layout will be like this:
  `[widget_2, widget_3, widget_4]`
- start a new cycle, now `i` is 1
- `takeAt(1)` will now take what *before* was the second item, so it will return the item for `widget_3`, skipping `widget_2`

If you do it using `reversed` this won't happen, and all widgets will be correctly removed starting from the last, up to the first.

Note that, if the field structure is always the same, your approach is not a very good one, since you could reuse existing fields instead of deleting them and creating new ones each time. Consider keeping references to the QLabels you're adding to the layout (`self.img`, `self.name`, etc.), and use `setPixmap()` or [`setText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) instead.